# Is there a jQuery plugin like DataTables for a <ul>?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, datatables

Is there any jQuery plugin that applies paging, allows users to select the page size, and manages displaying user's current position in the results (e.g. 'Showing results: 1-5 of 230')?  I want to load all the list items into the 'ul' on initial page load, and apply the paging afterword.

[DataTables](http://datatables.net/) appears to do all of this (and more), but it doesn't work with a 'ul'.

Here is a wireframe screenshot for what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Example Wireframe]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to build one yourself. A function that hides list elements `li:gt(results*pagenum - 1)` and `li:lt(results*(pagenum-1))` might do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, I may go that direction.  It's just a shame to not be able to use the beautifully refined features of DataTables that already exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research I have not found an equivalent to DataTables that works with `<ul>`s.

Because the website is internal website and DataTables is so robust, I went with DataTables. The page renders a single-column table, and the styling is tweaked to hide the table header and footer.  In the end, it looked exactly like the wireframe above. It's just a shame that the markup has to be polluted with the ugly `<table>` tags.

Comment: hi, can you tell me how can you unstylize datatable? even if i only delete thead i get some errors. and how can you remove thead section? thanks

Comment: Tuxi, I unstyled the datatable and hid the thead all in the CSS file.  Just add the CSS: #mydatatable thead {display: none;} Unstyling the rest of the datatable is a little more tedious, but you can remove unnecessary elements easily by using the sDom (datatables.net/ref#sDom) parameter while creating the table.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to change your `UL`/`LI`s to a `table` *on the fly* and then attach `dataTables()`. This example adds a jQuery extension method called `dataList` that converts any target `ULs` to a `TABLE` (but leaves existing tables alone):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r5xf61zp/5/

```
$.fn.dataList = function (options) {
    this.each(function () {
        var $table = $(this);
        if ($table.is('ul')) {
            var $ul = $table;
            $table = $ul.wrap('<table><tbody/></table').closest('table');
            $ul.find('li').wrap('<tr><td/></tr>').contents().unwrap();
            $ul.contents().unwrap()
            $table.prepend('<thead><tr><th>Heading</th></tr></thead>');
        }
        $table.dataTable(options);
    });
}
```

And use just like `.dataTable()`:

```
$('.example').dataList({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});
```

*The only outstanding issue is what to display for the heading (currently `Heading` in the example* :)

### Update - (added heading support)

Just revisiting this one and decided the best way to provide a heading would be via a `data-heading` attribute on the `UL`.

Example in HTML:

```
<ul class="example" data-heading="My new heading">
```

Code:

```
$.fn.dataList = function (options) {
    this.each(function () {
        var $table = $(this);
        if ($table.is('ul')) {
            var $ul = $table;
            $table = $ul.wrap('<table><tbody/></table').closest('table');
            $ul.find('li').wrap('<tr><td/></tr>').contents().unwrap();
            $ul.contents().unwrap()
            $table.prepend('<thead><tr><th>' + ($ul.data('heading') || '') + '</th></tr></thead>');
        }
        $table.dataTable(options);
    });
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r5xf61zp/8/