# How to achieve pagination using jQuery Datatable where I've used ul and li tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I want to achieve pagination in my list using jQuery datables, how can I achieve it? It's obvious that we need to declare table tag for using it, but I have no idea how to use in this case. Any help? Following shows my code which displays the lists of some data.

```
@model IEnumerable<ESportsScreening.Models.Screening>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
    <ul class="screenings" id="theList">


        @foreach (var scr in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <div class="date">
                    <div class="month">
                        @scr.DateTime.ToString("MMM")
                    </div>
                    <div class="day">
                        @scr.DateTime.ToString("d ")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="details1">
                    <div>
                        <strong>@scr.TeamA vs @scr.TeamB</strong><small> (@scr.Competition.Name) </small>
                    </div>
                    <div>@scr.Organizer.Organizer</div>
                    <div>
                        <small>@scr.Organizer.Street, @scr.Organizer.City</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="details2">
                    <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="Details" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Details", "Screenings")?id=' + @scr.Id" />
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to keep the ul/li structure, or that you want to convert that to a table?

Comment: this one already have solution [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400033/is-there-a-jquery-plugin-like-datatables-for-a-ul](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400033/is-there-a-jquery-plugin-like-datatables-for-a-ul)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a jQuery plugin like DataTables for a <ul>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400033/is-there-a-jquery-plugin-like-datatables-for-a-ul)